# Easy way to save a static binary tree in compile time

Tags: c++

I want to save a static binary tree at compile time, currently my idea is like this:

```
struct Node {
  int id;
  Node *father;
  Node *children;
};

Node tree[] = {
    {0, nullptr, tree + 1}, {1, tree, tree + 3}, {2, tree, tree + 5}, {3, tree + 1, nullptr}, {4, tree + 1, nullptr},
    {5, tree + 2, nullptr}, {6, tree + 2, nullptr}
};
```

It is way annoying to write things like this by hand, and if the data structure is complicated, hand writing code seems impossible. So is there a better way to save a const static tree, or even `constexpr` tree?

Note: this is not a real problem, I just curious how far I go on this "compile time structure" thing.

Comment: This might be a bit too verbose, but you could create a bunch of named variables rather than an array.  Then you can reference the father/children by name.

Comment: In this situation, an experienced C++ developer will likely have some external means of defining the binary tree, maybe in terms of XML, or YAML, or something along those lines; and then have a script that robo-generates C++ code that looks pretty much like that; but, in general, this is too broad, and opinionated question.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm variables by name cannot be done in this example, since a node both have father and children, this will cause identifier not defined problem.

Comment: Your example is a complete binary tree, yet your use of explicit parent and child pointers suggest that the tree need not be complete. Do you need to account for a non-complete binary tree?

Comment: @JaMiT I didn't think that much, I just use binary tree as an example for the sake of simplicity. In this case, of cause I can use an algorithm to get the parent and child. Without loss of generality, this question seeks for a common way to save any fixed data structure.

Comment: @ravenisadesk With that phrasing, what you seek seems rather ambitious, as there is no common way to *store* (in memory) any fixed data structure. There are several approaches to storing data structures, each with advantages and disadvantages, and that is without the restriction that the structure be assembled by the compiler. You might be better off focusing on a specific data structure (and thinking "that much" about it while framing your question -- the question can be interesting, but details matter).

Comment: @JaMiT, I got typo here, by means of "any fixed data structure", I mean"any fixed tree data structure"

Answer (score 0):

You can build up the tree at compile time using `constexpr`.

Start by writing a generic binary tree insertion function:

```
constexpr void insert_node(Node *root, Node *ins)
{
    if (root->val > ins->val) {
        if (root->left) {
            insert_node(root->left, ins);
        } else {
            root->left = ins;
        }
    } else {
        if (root->right) {
            insert_node(root->right, ins);
        } else {
            root->right = ins;
        }
    }
};
```

Specify all the values of the tree using a brace-enclosed list (in any order you want):

```
Node tree[] = {11,4,50,3,2,8,99,12,6,10};
```

Update your `struct Node` so that when each node is constructed, any previous nodes have their pointers updated:

```
struct Node {
    constexpr Node(int val)
        : left(nullptr), right(nullptr), val(val)
    {
        if (tree != this) {
            insert_node(tree, this);
        }
    }
    Node *left;
    Node *right;
    int val;
};
```

This should be legal because arrays are guaranteed by the standard to be initialized one element at a time, left to right. When the first element in `tree` (the root) is initialized, we simply use the provided value. When the second element is initialized we use the provided value, but "go back" and update one of the root child pointers as needed.

With the above code (and some forward declarations) I was able to confirm the above works in g++-8

Note because initializing a node in the tree requires changing previous already initialized nodes, I don't think it's possible to make the tree `const` or `constexpr`. When using `constexpr` you cannot "go back" and modify already initialized objects, even at compile time.

However if you are willing to use a `const_cast`, you can make the array `constexpr` and have it stored in the `.rodata` section. Simply use `insert_node(const_cast<Node*>(tree), this);` in the constructor. This works for me with `g++`, although it's probably a violation of the standard because it's modifying an already constructed const object.

Now if you hex dump the compiled executable you'll see the the actual tree (with all the filled in pointers) in the binary itself, instead of being generated in a constructor at runtime.